# Cross-validation of (Cox) survival model with very high censoring rate

Tags: cross-validation, cox-model, rms

I am currently working on survival analysis of data with very high censoring rate (~99%), and the number of events is only about 500, using R.

I would like to ask in such case, whether the validate() in the rms package is suitable for cross-validation?

If so, how to interpret the output? What values would indicate the model in inappropriate or possibly overfitting?

If not, do you have suggestions for how to perform cross-validation?

Thanks in advance.